# Rstan not working with multi-core support

Tags: r, rstan

I installed R version 3.5.1 (on Windows 7 x64 desktop PC) following by Rtools 3.5 and rstan (via install.packages())

Rstan is failing with multi-core support like so:

```
library(rstan)
rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE)
options(mc.cores = 3) # or any number above 2
fit <- stan(file = '8schools.stan', data = schools_dat, 
            iter = 3, chains = 4)
```

with error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  4 nodes produced errors; first error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/ubashir/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpIHGdm6/file194833bbb82.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  Access is denied.
```

However if i change the options line to:

```
options(mc.cores = 1) # or any other number up to 8
```

The code  works. Anyone know a solution besides using only 1 core?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There exist two relevant issues on the [`rstan` GitHub project site](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan): [Issue #491](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/491) and [Issue #492](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/492).

This issue seems to be related to an empty `/etc/hosts` file. I don't own a Windows machine, but this file seems to reside in `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.

You need to make sure that the file contains a line:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

If necessary edit and save the file, and try again. (You potentially might have to do the whole restart Windows shenanigans...)

Comment: Hi, I work on a company PC and they don't allow any changes to the etc / hosts file.

Comment: @Maelstorm Then you have to ask your sysadmin; there's not much else you can do (other than run `rstan` in single core mode).

Comment: Hi, I just had that line added by sysadmin, and the error remains. I suspect something else is playing up. Thanks for your help.